# VS2008 Illegal Reading Of String Text

Tags: c#, asp.net

I declaring a string of Special Characters.

```
var SpecialCharSequence = "',!,#,$,%,&,',(,),*,+,-,.,\,/,:,;,<,=,>,?,@,[,],^,_,{,|,},~,";
```

Why its giving a error for backward Slash

```
Unrecognized escape sequence
```

When already its in Quotation marks.

Comment: Try using `SpecialCharSequence = @"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thats because your string contains \ which is an escape character.

replace `\` with `\\`.

```
var SpecialCharSequence = "',!,#,$,%,&,',(,),*,+,-,.,\\,/,:,;,<,=,>,?,@,[,],^,_,{,|,},~,";
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare like this: (with the verbatim literal @ )

```
var SpecialCharSequence = @"',!,#,$,%,&,',(,),*,+,-,.,\,/,:,;,<,=,>,?,@,[,],^,_,{,|,},~,";
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

An `\` results in an escape sequence, which you have in your string.
Convert it to `\\` and it will work. `\` is a special sign, and to represent the literal `\` you need double of them.

Answer (score 0):

The `\` is an escape character.  If you want to use the `string` with a single `\`, then add `@` at the start of the `string` making it a `literal string`.  Otherwise, you'll need to escape the single `\` with a second `\\`.

`var SpecialCharSequence = @"',!,#,$,%,&,',(,),*,+,-,.,\,/,:,;,<,=,>,?,@,[,],^,_,{,|,},~,";`

Answer (score 0):

Because the backwards slash means it will be a character escape in combination with the next char.

Like \t means a tab, \r means return.

You could either use \ to mean a backslash, or you can use a verbatim string (by adding the @ before the string), like this:

```
var SpecialCharSequence = @"',!,#,$,%,&,',(,),*,+,-,.,\,/,:,;,<,=,>,?,@,[,],^,_,{,|,},~,";
```

In a verbatim string, you're telling the compiler that you are not using character escapes in this string...